# Proguard - Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/d/kl]

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, facebook-audience-network

I am failing to create a release build. Suddenly Android Studio started throwing below error.

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [com/google/android/gms/d/lc]
  Method      = [a(Lcom/google/android/gms/d/kk;Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/android/gms/d/lh;Lcom/google/android/gms/d/en;Lcom/google/android/gms/d/lb;)Lcom/google/android/gms/d/kn;]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/d/kn] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes))
Unexpected error while preverifying:
  Class       = [com/google/android/gms/d/lc]
  Method      = [a(Lcom/google/android/gms/d/kk;Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/android/gms/d/lh;Lcom/google/android/gms/d/en;Lcom/google/android/gms/d/lb;)Lcom/google/android/gms/d/kn;]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/d/kn] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes))
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/d/kn] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes)
```

Here is my Proguard Configurations

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class com.facebook.ads.** { *; }
```

Here is the list of gradle dependencies of my project

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.8.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.28.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.4.9'   
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

**Note** Commenting the Facebook audience network dependency fixes the error. Unfortunately I cannot do it permanently from the project.

Please help me identifying the cause of an issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue after updating the studio, please let me know if you find the solution of this.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki, I have posted my workaround. Please check if it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I managed to fix the error. As I am not Proguard expert, I may be wrong but this is the workaround I see at the moment.

As I have mentioned in the question, Facebook Audience Network causes the problem with the release build and errors are associated with the GMS Play Service library. According to [comment](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/audience-network-sdk/4.28.2) posted by @pedrofsn, Facebook Audience Network uses the Google Play Service Ads library.

I started looking into [documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedclass) for the error `Can't find common super class of`. It says that

> A class in one of your program jars or library jars is referring to a
>   class or interface that is missing from the input. The warning lists
>   both the referencing class(es) and the missing referenced class(es).
>   There can be a few reasons, with their own solutions:

As it says the warning lists both the referencing class(es) and the missing referenced class(es), I decided to remove `dontwarn` just to see the warnings by the Proguard & updated my Proguard Configuration as below

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }

-keep class com.facebook.ads.** { *; }
```

I managed to see all the warnings by Proguard as the screenshot below.

[image]

As we can see from the screenshot, google ads library classes cannot find their referenced class `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac`. My guess is that this class `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac` should belong to the internal jar of the google ads dependency & that internal jar is probably missing.

So I have manually added the google ads dependency to my app level `build.gradle` as below

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

And I see I can compile the release build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed downgrading 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0' to 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'

Comment: I have tried downgrading all the dependencies but no luck. I tried the option invalidate caches & restart after downgrading dependencies but it throws the same error.

Comment: Do you have Facebook Audience Network dependency added in your project?

Comment: No, I haven't Facebook Audience Network dependecy added in my project. The error says "Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/d/kn]". The problem it's specific with GMS Play Services, maybe you've a lib that is using a specific version of GMS Play Services.

Comment: But removing the Facebook Audience Network dependency gives no error & I can build the release versison. My guess is the the Facebook Audience network itself is messing around with the specific GMS play services.

Comment: Facebook Audience Network compile with play services, look this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/audience-network-sdk/4.28.0.

Comment: Yes, I see play service ads 15.0.1 is being used by the Facebook audience network but unfortunately cannot figure it out how to relate it with this issue as downgrading other dependencies of my project is also not working. Could there be an other way around to think about the google play ads 15.0.1 existing in the Facebook Audience Network?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, I had to uncomment:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        //minifyEnabled true
        //shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

and add the below to your proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

although uncommenting `minifyEnabled` is **not recommended** since it removes dead/unused code