# I am getting Error in generating Production Release Apk. my error is

Tags: android

```
Unmanaged thread operation #-1 (Tasks limiter_1)    103ms
Resolve files of :app:productionReleaseRuntimeClasspath 102ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to design.aar (com.android.support:design:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to duo-navigation-drawer.aar (nl.psdcompany:duo-navigation-drawer:2.0.6)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to facebook-android-sdk.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to facebook-common.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.35.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to LinearTimer.aar (com.github.krtkush:LinearTimer:v2.1.1)    2ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to facebook-login.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.35.0)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to appcompat-v7.aar (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to facebook-share.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.35.0)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to cardview-v7.aar (com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to cardview-v7.aar (com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to audience-network-sdk.aar (com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to recyclerview-v7.aar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1)   1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to recyclerview-v7.aar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-auth.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-location.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-messaging.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-drive.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-analytics.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-auth-api-phone.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-auth-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-core.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0)   10ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-measurement-connector-impl.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:16.0.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-analytics.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-analytics.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.0.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.0.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-iid.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-iid.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0)   1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0)   1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:16.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:16.0.0)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:16.0.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-ads.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1)    3ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-iid-interop.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-clearcut.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:10.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to recyclerview-v7.aar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1)   33ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-places-placereport.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-measurement-connector.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to firebase-measurement-connector.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-stats.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-stats.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-stats.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-stats.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-stats.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-ads-identifier.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-ads-identifier.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-ads-identifier.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-ads-lite.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:10.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-gass.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:10.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to circleimageview.aar (de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to constraint-layout.aar (com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to pgplussdk.aar (com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.1.5)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to multidex.aar (com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to transition.aar (com.android.support:transition:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to facebook-places.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-places:4.35.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to facebook-applinks.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.35.0)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to facebook-messenger.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:4.35.0)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to facebook-marketing.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:4.35.0)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to facebook-core.aar (com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.35.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to exoplayer-dash.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.2)    1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to exoplayer-core.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.2)    
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to customtabs.aar (com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1)  21ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-fragment.aar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to animated-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to animated-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1)   1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)   1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)   1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)   
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-media-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-media-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-core-utils.aar (com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) 1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-measurement-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-measurement-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-measurement-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4)  1ms
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-measurement-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-measurement-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to play-services-measurement-base.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to runtime.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to livedata-core.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0) 
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0)  
Apply org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.VariantAttributeMatchingCache$1@16c17bb to viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0) 
null    
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/c/ks] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/lang/String] (with 2 known super classes)
```

Comment: are you using proguard?

Comment: Checkout this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622234/3974530

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

add this line to your proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `proguard` then consider adding custom Proguard Rule according to libraries you are using in your Application.

Like Firebase, Admob, Picasso, Glide, Okhttp or Okio require some custom Proguard Rule.

Hope it helps.