# Generate signed APK build runs forever when minifyEnabled is true

Tags: android, android-studio, build, signed-apk, shrinkresources

I'm trying to reduce the APK size. So as suggested by Google I used `shrinkResources` and it requires `minifyEnabled` to be `true` in `bulid.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

But the problem is once this is done, the build never ends.

[image]

`proguard-rules.pro` is empty I haven't changed anything in it. And, something called `Unmanaged thread operation #-1` also appeared.

What would be the issue?

Comment: see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583150/proguard-cant-find-common-super-class-of-com-google-android-gms-d-kl/50622234#50622234) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821712/i-am-getting-error-in-generating-production-release-apk-my-error-is?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build finally ended after running for `16m 17s`. Although normal APK generate takes about 3 minutes, it is worth waiting because the apk size was actually reduced in about 52% compared to a normal signed apk

```
normal apk  : 4585 KB
minified apk: 2170 KB
```